# NodeJS Process.on Bidirectional Communication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a simple NodeJS application, where there are a parent process and child process.

Both are communicating with each other. Below is the code.

**parent.js**

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const { fork } = require('child_process');
const forked = fork('./child.js');


forked.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from child', msg);
});

forked.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

**child.js**

```
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from parent: ', msg);
});


let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  process.send({ counter: counter++ });
}, 1000);
```

**Expected Output**

```
  Message from parent: {hello: "world"}
  Message from child { counter: 0 }
  Message from child { counter: 1 }
  Message from child { counter: 2 }
  Message from child { counter: 3 }
  Message from child { counter: 4 }
    ......and so on
```

But I am not getting `Message from parent: {hello : "world"}`

I am getting this as

**Output**

```
  Message from child { counter: 0 }
  Message from child { counter: 1 }
  Message from child { counter: 2 }
  Message from child { counter: 3 }
  Message from child { counter: 4 }
    ......and so on
```

**Environment**

- **OS**: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- **NodeJS**: 14.6.0

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "simple-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "latest",
    "body-parser": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "api": "nodemon ./server/server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"nodemon server/server.js\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "latest",
    "nodemon": "latest"
  }
}
```

So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your code looks exactly the same as given in the [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) so I don't see any reason why it should not work. Just ran it on my machine and got your expected output

Comment: @t348575 Even I am wondering why this behaviour I am getting in my machine. I am using updated NodeJS version(v14.6.0) on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Tried on ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with node 14.6.0 and it worked fine

Comment: @t348575 It got the solution. Actually, due to the ``asynchronous, `` nature of the **ES module** loading, there is a **race condition** in my script. Since I am using ``"type": "module"`` in my **package.json** and my project is huge, I can't change ES module loading. So you overcome the race condition I have to delay a little sending message to the child process. Thus ``setTimeout(() = >{forked.send({ hello: 'world' });, 100};`` avoids race condition.

Comment: Timeout may not be reliable in case of a process scheduling mishap, maybe wait for a message from the child stating it is alive before sending messages from the parent.

Comment: @t348575 You are correct but in my case, this parent and child are just normal process which will be working in the background without creating any obstruction to any other process.

Comment: So does it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, due to the `asynchronous`, nature of the **ES module** loading, there is a `race condition` in my script.

Since I am using

> `"type": "module"`

In my **package.json** and my project is huge, I can't change ES module loading.

So you overcome the `race condition` I have to **delay** a little **sending message** to the `child process`.

Thus,

```
   setTimeout(() = >{
        forked.send({ hello: 'world' });
    , 100};
```

avoids race condition.